# Javascript function fire order when used as callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I created a little fetch function that basically just does an ajax `POST` for me along with a number of other things that I've removed for the sake of brevity. In this function I pass a callback which should fire when the success callback is hit.

```
function ajax_fetch(url, fetch, data, callback) {     

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: baseurl + url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            fetch.html(response);

            // if there's a callback, run it.
            if (typeof callback == "function")
                callback();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            handleErrors(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

Below I have a piece of code where I am essentially doing 2 ajax calls. The first one fires a normal ajax `POST` and then upon success, calls my `ajax_fetch()` function above, all works as intended.

```
$("#markstatus").singleBind("click", function () {
    var step = "{ step : " + $(this).data("step") + "}";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl + "SetStatus",
        data: step,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#header.container").html(result);
            ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", $(".replaceable"), step,
            function() {
                window.alerts.success("Step Complete");
            });              
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            handleErrors(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

However here is the problem:

```
$("#removestatus").singleBind("click", function () {

    var step = "{ step : " + $(this).data("step") + "}";

    ajax_fetch("RemoveStatus", $("#header.container"), step,
        ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", $(".replaceable"), step,
        function () {
            window.alerts.warning("Step Re-Opened");
        })
    );
});
```

I thought I could be tricky and do essentially the same double ajax call by using my `ajax_fetch()` function initially, and then upon hitting the first callback pass in another `ajax_fetch()` all should be fine and dandy.

But when I look at my console output:

```
customSpa.js:793 Object {url: "/StepIndex", fetch: jQuery.fn.init[1], data: "{ step : 1}", callbackl: function}
customSpa.js:801 requesting: /async//StepIndex
customSpa.js:793 Object {url: "RemoveStatus", fetch: jQuery.fn.init[1], data: "{ step : 1}", callbackl: undefined}
customSpa.js:801 requesting: /async/RemoveStatus
```

I can see that it is calling the inner fetch first, then the outer. Is this an async / promise type of issue or what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: What is `singleBind()`? It sounds like it should be the same as [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: yeah singleBind() is something I added myself to do just an .off() and .on() so that if i rebind a handler after an ajax event that it wont fire multiple times... looks like JQ already took care of that by .one(), go figure, whenever i do something I think is smart, it's already done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function as a callback (to be called later on), but you are passing *the result of immediately calling a function instead*.

You need to write the call like this:

```
ajax_fetch("RemoveStatus", $("#header.container"), step,
    function() {
        ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", $(".replaceable"), step,
        function () {
            window.alerts.warning("Step Re-Opened");
        })
    }
);
```

...which should not be surprising. The inner callback is a function; the outer callback must be a function as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ajax_fetch`, it is performing the ajax call at that time.  You are not passing the function as a callback, you are calling that function here:

```
ajax_fetch("RemoveStatus", $("#header.container"), step,
    ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", $(".replaceable"), step, // this makes the call
    function () {
        window.alerts.warning("Step Re-Opened");
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the Promise feature of jQuery instead of deep nesting.

You therefore would return the `jqXHR` of your `$.ajax` call as result from your `ajax_fetch` function. As it implements the Promise interface you can call `.then` on it and in the `then`-callback you do your next `ajax_fetch` call and return the `jqXHR` there also.

```
function ajax_fetch(url, fetch, data) {     

    return $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: baseurl + url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            fetch.html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            handleErrors(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
}



$("#removestatus").singleBind("click", function () {

    var step = "{ step : " + $(this).data("step") + "}";

    ajax_fetch("RemoveStatus", $("#header.container"), step)
    .then(function() {
      return ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", $(".replaceable"), step);
    })
    .then(function() {
      window.alerts.warning("Step Re-Opened");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the reason you are getting the error is that `ajax_fetch(..., ..., ..., function () {...})` is a function call, not a function.

In addition, you are doing a couple of things that make the code unnecessarily complicated.

- It is unnecessary to pass `fetch` and `callback` to ajax_fetch(). By returning from the function the jqXHR object generated by $.ajax(...), any calling function can handle the response in a chained `.then()`, and also handle an error condition at the end of the chain.
- `step` does not need to be a hand-coded JSON string. It can be written as an object literal and the resulting object used directly as the ajax `.data` property. Thus, `contentType: "application/json",` can disappear.

You should end up with :

```
function ajax_fetch(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
    ^^^^^^
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl + url,
        data: data,
        dataType: "html"
    });
}
```

And the two calling functions will be as follows :

```
$("#markstatus").singleBind('click', function () {
    var step = { step: $(this).data('step') };
    ajax_fetch("SetStatus", step).then(function (result) {
        $("#header.container").html(result);
        return ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", step).then(function(response) {
            $(".replaceable").html(response);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        window.alerts.success("Step Complete");
    }, handleErrors);
});

$("#removestatus").singleBind('click', function () {
    var step = { step: $(this).data('step') };
    ajax_fetch('RemoveStatus', step).then(function(result) {
        $("#header.container").html(result);
        return ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", step).then(function (response) {
            $(".replaceable").html(response);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        window.alerts.warning("Step Re-Opened");
    }, handleErrors);
});
```

The two event handlers are so similar, you could combine them. You just need a mechanism to manage the differences, which are :

- the part path passed to ajax_fetch() as `url`
- the warning message.

First, set up some data for each of the clickable elements.

```
$("#markstatus").data('params', {
    'path':'SetStatus',
    'message':'Step Complete'
});
$("#removestatus").data('params', {
    'path':'RemoveStatus',
    'message':'Step Re-Opened'
});
```

Then attach a single click handler to both elements.

```
$("#markstatus, #removestatus").singleBind('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        step = { 'step': $this.data('step') },
        params = $this.data('params');
    ajax_fetch(params.path, step).then(function(result) {
        $("#header.container").html(result);
        return ajax_fetch("/StepIndex", step).then(function (response) {
            $(".replaceable").html(response);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        window.alerts.warning(params.message);
    }, handleErrors);
});
```

Comment: thanx roamer. i'm actually in the process of cleaning this up right now which is what led me to trying to combine some things and get rid of a bunch of redundant and inefficient code. I appreciate the suggestions.